# UnityScript generating UnityEngine error

Tags: unity, animation, events, unityscript

I have the following code set out for a simple animation in Unity:

```
#pragma strict
function Start () {

}

function Update () {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("KeyCode.W")){
        animation.Play("dogWalk", WrapMode.Loop);
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea what to do with namespaces (since they occasionally pop up as warnings but don't seem to have any purpose), and line 12 (animation.Play("dogWalk", WrapMode.Loop);) keeps generating an error regarding UnityEngine. What does it mean, and how do I fix it?

TL;DR:

- What do namespaces do?
- What does the error mean and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Error is ""No appropriate version of "UnityEngine.AnimationPlay" for the argument list".

Comment: Could you show where the namespace code is referring to?

Comment: If you ever have a problem with an error code, try searching the error message with Google. If you can't find anything, when you ask the question, you should post the exact error message text.

Comment: @Byte66 That is the exact error, I'll search it anyway though.

Comment: @Sidar I'm not sure. All I know is that UnityEngine is one and that the code was complaining that I didn't have any.

Comment: The problem seems to have solved itself. I'm not really sure how, but now it's just telling me to set up the keyCode rather than patch the syntax itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Namespaces are like "virtual folders" where you put your classes in. Just in code. Like how Packages work in Java or AS3. Eventhough in those two languages they are explicitly structured in  actual folders too. It prevents Class names to conflict with each other and it allows for vendors to be denoted.

For example:

```
com.paulsoft.game.MyObject;
```

Like @Tetrad said, you're passing an argument to the function that is invalid.

Comment: In fact, Unity *does* support scripts in namespaces since version 4.0, it just isn't reflected in the documentation for some reason.

Comment: That's weird =/ well i removed it in my answer.

Comment: Thanks :). My scripting experience is limited to websites, so games give me a lot to get used to.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling animation.Play with the wrong argument types.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Animation.Play.html

The second parameter is a [`PlayMode`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayMode.html), not a `WrapMode`.

Comment: You may use PlayMode for stopping animations, but the scripting reference says you use WrapMode to define how they run (as a loop, once, etc). But I'm not sure how well I'm using it, since it isn't working and all.